# text wrapping below image

Tags: html, css

I have a small image and i have to show some text beside that image. for that i have used the below html and css.

```
<div class="main">
   <img alt="image"/>
   <h2>this is heading text. This is heading text. This is heading text</h2>
</div>


.main{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    padding:20px;
}
h2{
    display:inline;
}
```

it is showing like this

[image]

The second line is wrapping below the image. I have to get the second line just below the first line not below the image.

I tried using float also. but not working. please help.

I created a fiddle so you can edit it easily: http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/MtqHh/1/

Comment: You could add a bottom margin to the image which will stop the text falling under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply float the image, and push the h2 across with a left margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/MtqHh/8/

```
img { float: left; }

h2{ margin: 0 0 0 50px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

hope it will help you

```
   .main{
border:1px solid black;
height:200px;
width:400px;
padding:20px;
  }
   h2{
      display: flex;
    }
   img{
    float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  }
```

Working demo  http://jsfiddle.net/MtqHh/13/

Answer (score 1):

```
.main{
        border:1px solid black;
        height:200px;
        width:400px;
        padding:20px;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
.main img{
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

h2{
    float:left; 
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding;0px;
    margin:0px;
    }
```

use this code usefull for you. and see this link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/MtqHh/10/

Answer (score 1):

A good way of achieving this is shown on an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y5ewr/1/

The advantage is highlighted in the use of `overflow:hidden` on the `<h2>`. This means that if the `<img>` is not in place the heading will flow full width and no margins are needed on the heading element.